# Displaying a PDF file inside a form using visual c++

Tags: c++, pdf, visual-c++

I'm using visual c++ and i am totally new on it.
I have a form with a button, how when i click on it the file will open in new form?.
I tried to find a solution around but in vain.

Comment: What have you produced so far? Show us your code...

Comment: I figured it out  I will post the code so it can be used by other people if they face my problem

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add Adobe Reader COM component  to your Toolbox.

Than drag it (like a simple button )into your "Form2" and name it AdRead for example.

In your first Form insert this code to your button so you can open "Form2"

```
         Form2 ^ anyname = gcnew Form2();
         anyname->Show();
         this->Hide();
```

And put this code into AdRead

```
String^ Path ="here put the path of your specific file";
AdRead->src=Path;
```

Your path should be like  `"c:\\folder\\folder\\File.pdf"`